# How to derect Errors via Soupsession or SoupMessage Signals?

Tags: c, webkit, glib

Im currently developing with WebkitGtk+ Unstable Api
I'm using Soupsession Object to conect Signals and Rertve Soupmessages to (again)
hook signals to every Message to obtain time details of network events, my problem is how to monitor errors from this point.

if I'm using just the signal, there is a way to detect when a network error like DNS error or a socket error ocurrs i searched over the SoupSession Manuals but found nothing usable.

can someone give me some guidances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago i figured it out.
the errors are reported in the responce http code of the soup message

https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/libsoup-2.4-soup-status.html

I just needed to capture the status code in the soup message signal "finished" to know if the resource failed (and why) or if was successful